# jQuery: UI widget definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a widget defined like so:

```
$.widget("ui.mywidget", {
    _init: function() {
        this.element.bind("keyup", function(event) {
            alert(this.options);
            alert(this.options.timeout);
        });
    }
});
```

And trying to call it like so:

```
$("input.mywidget").mywidget({timeout: 5});
```

I also redefined the `bind` method using the `this.element.keyup(function(event) { ... })` style: no difference.

But, in the `keyup` bind, `this.options` (and referencing it just as `options`) both yield undefined. I thought the UI widget framework allowed this type of abstraction; am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When inside `bind()`, `this` changes to refer to the object that the event is raised on. Try:

```
$.widget("ui.mywidget", {
    _init: function(options) {
        var opts = this.options;
        this.element.bind("keyup", function(event) {
            alert(opts);
            alert(opts.timeout);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: In the widget framework is the `_create()` or `_init()` method more appropriate for this kind of binding?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the framework to be able to say, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

What @Dave said is right. You can also set "this" to a variable rather than using options as an argument to the init function. Here is how I see it implemented often:

```
$.widget("ui.mywidget", {
    options: {
        timeout: 100
    },
    _init: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.element.bind("keyup", function(event) {
            alert(self.options);
            alert(self.options.timeout);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why stop there?  Check out [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) and write better code

```
$.widget("ui.mywidget", {
    _create: function() {

        //Under this syntax, _omgAlertsRule must be a method of 'this'
        this.element.bind("keyup", $.proxy( this, '_omgAlertsRule' ) );
    },
    _omgAlertsRule: function( event ){

        alert(this.options);
        alert(this.options.timeout);
    }
});
```